# Specify decimal places using variables inside string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

I have a string format which includes two integer variables, each of which needs to be formatted to a variable length:

```
int x = 1234;
int y = 42;

// Simplified, real values come from method outputs, so must use the variables:
int xFormatDigitCount = 7;
int yFormatDigitCount = 3; 

var xStringFormat = new string('0', xFormatDigitCount); // "0000000"
var yStringFormat = new string('0' ,yFormatDigitCount); // "000"
```

For now I only managed to get the desired format using the integer variables' `.ToString()` methods:

```
var xString = x.ToString(xStringFormat);
var yString = y.ToString(yStringFormat);
return $"{xString}-{yString}";
```

But this seems like an overhead since string interpolation supports the format {var:format}. Is there a way to get my string with only string interpolation, without using x and y's `ToString()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get my string with only string interpolation, without using x and y's ToSTring()

I don't believe so, but it can be so much cleaner thanks to `ToString("Dx")`:

All in one (nested interpolations):

```
public string Format(int x, int y, int xDigitCount, int yDigitCount)
{
    return $"{x.ToString($"D{xDigitCount}")}-{y.ToString($"D{yDigitCount}")}";
}
```

Stack Overflow syntax highlighting can't keep up, so it looks odd, but this is how it looks in VS:

[image]

Comment: For me, that gives `1 234.0000000-42.000` instead of  `0001234-042`. Don't you mean `D` instead of `N`?

Comment: Best answers my question ("I don't believe so"), plus improves on my initial solution :) marked as accepted answer. Could you please update the screenshot in order to avoid readers' confusion?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but format specifiers for `string.Format` and, thus, string interpolation are textual - they don't accept variables.

You either use static format specifiers:

```
$"{x:0000000}-{y:000}"
```

Or resort to the good old `string.Format`:

```
string.Format(
    $"{{0:{new string('0', xFormatDigitCount)}}}-{{1:{new string('0', yFormatDigitCount)}}}",
    x,
    y);
```

**Edit:**

Based on [weston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360211/weston)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34678703/402366):

```
$"{x.ToString($"D{xFormatDigitCount}")}-{y.ToString($"D{yFormatDigitCount}")}"
```

Comment: Why are you specifying `}` using additional arguments instead of `}}`? `string.Format("{{0:{0}}}-{{1:{1}}}", new string('0', xFormatDigitCount), new string('0', yFormatDigitCount))` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Once upon a time I was bitten by a problem regarding `}` on `string.Format` and I started following the [recommendation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format). I've changed it to string interpolation as another way of doing what you said.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `ToString` method within the interpolated string.

```
$"{x.ToString(xStringFormat)}-{y.ToString(yStringFormat)}"
```